# Android : Bluetooth : Showing In Range Devices nearby

Tags: android, bluetooth

Android : BLUETOOTH :

I am trying to flag a device as "In Range" with following method :

Inside the BroadCast Receiver following condition is written :
If `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND` is true and the device is `BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED` ,  then
the phone is " In Range "

**Problem :**

Suppose a Device Called 'ABC' is shown as "In Range" ; now if i turn off the bluetooth of this Client Device 'ABC' , the code is still showing as "In Range" ?

Code Snippet :

```
protected void onStart() {<br>
super.onStart();<br>
        newListView.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClicked);<br>
        final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {<br>
            @Override<br>
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {<br>
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {<br>
            BluetoothDevice device = intent<br>
                            .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);<br>
            if ((device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)) {<br>
             // Do Something<br>
            } else {<br>

                        for(BluetoothDevice newDevice : arrayOnlineBluetoothDevices)<br>
                        {<br>
                            if (newDevice.getAddress().equals(device.getAddress()))<br>
                            {<br>
                                flag=true;<br>
                            continue;<br>
                            }<br>
                        }<br>
                        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName());<br>
                        rangeListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter); // This is where I Tag any Device as <br>
                    }<br>
                    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);<br>
                    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);<br>
            }}}}<br>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for an ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT action in the BroadcastReceiver. This may take some time to occur after you switch the bluetooth of your device off. Typically about 10 seconds.